# Javadoc linked to api sources

Tags: java, api, javadoc

Do you know sites where javadoc api library has hyperlinks to sources of each api method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Guava API doc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html) links to the source code. You just need to use the [-linksource option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#linksource) of javadoc to do that. I wish more open-source projects use this option.